# Как и какой сделать элемент некликабельным, но чтобы его было видно на другом Layoyt' те (Android studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment, android-sdk

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

Делаю кликер игру, Стоит ConstraintLayout (на который когда кликаешь получаешь токены), в него поместил ImageView (небольшая картинка по центру, которую буду менять когда уровень будет повышаться). На данный момент ImageView не отображается по факту. Как сделать чтобы его было видно, но он был некликабельный (т.е. когда кликаю на ImageView, срабатывала логика ConstrainLayout) ? Спасибо.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fonv1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/level_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/level"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/money_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/money"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/basefonclicker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы установили `onClick Listener` и хотите его удалить, используйте:

```
imageView5.setOnClickListener(null);
```

Или же вы можете просто выключить нажатие, тогда

```
imageView5.setClickable(false);
```

---

> как сделать чтобы его было видно

Вы его не видите из-за отсутствия `@tools:sample/avatars`.  `tools: *` используется только для предварительного просмотра макета Android Studio. Вам нужно подставить свой `drawable`

Так же рекомендую выставить конкретные размеры `layout_width` и `layout_height` для `ImageView` и `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`

> когда его будет видно как сделать чтобы когда я на него нажимал, срабатывала логика как-будто я нажал на ConstraintLayout

Создать общий `onClick Listener` для `ConstraintLayout` и `ImageView`

Comment: Я не устанавливал onClicl listener для ImageView. На данный момент когда я запускаю приложения я даже не вижу этот ImageView почему-то, соответственно 2 вопроса:1  как сделать чтобы его было видно 2 когда его будет видно как сделать чтобы когда я на него нажимал, срабатывала логика как-будто я нажал на  ConstraintLayout, который под ним?

Comment: @Gennady, дополнил

Comment: Большое спасибо)